# Hardware Sizing for Video Apps

Tags: hardware, sizing

I need to do the Hardware sizing with following input:

- 600 concurrent users
- 200MB size video file access
- Users wll connect with streams with 64 KBps bitrate / 512 Kbps bit-rate
- Need to support 4 different types of file (live transcoding)

Can you please suggest the requirement of transcoding, streaming, gateway servers?

Comment: As per the FAQ, What kind of questions can I ask here? Questions not to ask "Product or service recommendations" Your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Well the streaming's easy, it's just 600 * 0.5Mbps (always base things on a worst case scenario), by the way even 0.5Mbps isn't great quality you know. So that works out at 300Mbps for streaming, which almost any single server should be able to keep up with, though do consider your storage (and/or caching). Depending volume requirements you'll need at least a pair of SATA 3 SSDs in R1/10 or 6-8 15krpm disks in R10 to get consistent 300Mbps of random read. You may wish to have a second streaming server for resilience behind a load-balancer.

As for your transcoder, you don't give us too much detail but why not start cheap, just get a server with a single 6-core cpu but with an empty socket, see how you get on and if you need the extra grunt you can just add the extra cpu as needed. Again consider having a second server for resilience.

Come back with more detail if you want.